# What does two-sided turnstile means in logic?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

I seem to not find this symbol on any other website or document and am struggling to find out its meaning: [two-sided turnstile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NceN.png)

The whole thing, for context purposes is: [context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kORco.png)

Or is it just another way to write double-turnstile?

Comment: What book is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that is a meta-logic symbol, not a logic symbol. That is, it expresses a connection between the logic statements $p \rightarrow q$ and $\neg p \lor q$.

One option is that it is used to express that using the rules of the system, the two statements can be derived from each other. As such, it would be equivalent to making the following two claims:

$p \rightarrow q \vdash \neg p \lor q$

and

$ \neg p \lor q \vdash p \rightarrow q$

However, I know I have also seen it expressing a rule of replacement, meaning that any $p \rightarrow q$ in any formula can be replaced by $\neg p \lor q$ and vice versa.

A rule of replacement is like a rule of inference, but different in two ways:

1. The inference goes both ways, rather than one way.
2. It can be applied to component statements.

EDIT

Now that you me the larger context, it is clear that the former is meant. So, you need to do two proofs: one where you infer $\neg p \lor q$ from $p \rightarrow q$, and one where you infer $p \rightarrow q$ from $\neg p \lor q$

Comment: The whole context would be: "Using only the introduction and elimination rules of standard propositional logic prove $ p \rightarrow q \dashv \vdash \neg p \lor q $ by natural deduction"

Comment: @Raizekas OK, so it is definitely not a Rule of Replacement then. So it could be meant to prove that the two are equivalent (where the assumption is that if you can, using the rules of Natural Deduction you do have, derive the one into the other, and vice versa, then that shows that equivalence) or it could be, as DanielV says, simply refer to the fact that they can be derived from each other, and nothing more. Either case, what you need to to is exactly that: show that you can derive $\neg p \lor q$ from $p \rightarrow q$, and vice versa, i.e. you need to do two proofs.

Comment: Yes, I would think it's probably the case of just proving how to derive from one to another, since it feels more like the information covered in the notes. Thanks once again, you're saving me so much today!

Comment: $\dashv\vdash$ is (in my experience) always used to denote equiprovability. See my answer. In the OP's example, the problem is to prove that $p \to q$ is provable iff $\lnot p \lor q$ is provable.

Comment: @Bram28: Can you give references for the use of $\dashv\vdash$ in either of the senses that you suggest?

Comment: @RobArthan I know I've seen it to define rules of replacement, but don't ask me where, sorry :(

Comment: @Bram28: thanks. Never mind. I think that $\dashv\vdash$ should be reserved for equiprovability.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I agree with you on that. It's frustrating that different books use different notations ... and with my answer I probably made the problem worse than better :( ... In fact, the larger context the OP gave makes clear equiprovability was meant here as well .. I'll edit my post. Thanks for pushing me on this!

Answer (score 2):

A sequent logic is a set of rules for using existing statements to create new statements.

A turnstyle, $A \vdash B$, indicates that the rules allow for $B$ to be created from $A$.

A double turnstyle indicates that the above holds as well as $A$ can be created from $B$, that is, they both can be created from each other by the set of rules.

If the logic is sound, then a double turnstyle will be equivalent to the $\iff$ (if and only if) operator, but if a logic isn't sound then a turnstyle or double turnstyle might not indicate anything useful at all.

Comment: $\vdash$ in the context of $\dashv\vdash$ is being used as a metanotation for equiprovability and not as part of an object language syntax for writing down sequents.